# Is Amazon EC2 instances good for plain webhosting?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm thinking about using an Amazon EC2 instance for hosting a few websites of mine. A personal homepage, a blog, etc. Is the cost low or should i grab a hosting package from HostGator or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting a root-account level system to host your personal sites to then you will find a VPS solution to be a much more cost advantage; however, if you're running a site that needs near instant scalability and redundancy where cost isn't an issue then EC2 instances are an ideal choice. Given the pricing model bandwidth is not that much of cost issue, however when you're talking running an instance 24 hours a day it becomes another story.

I currently run 10 EC2 instances 24/7 and bandwidth and storage are by far the lowest costs to factor in. If you take my [Linode](http://www.linode.com) VPS instance with 1024MB RAM I pay just around $40/month for it to run 24/7. Compare that to even an [Amazon Small](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#instance) (m1.small) EC2 instance which has 1.7GB RAM running 24/7 for 30 days you're talking 720 hours at $0.12/hr you're looking at $86.40 just in hourly run time costs. You can quickly see how that would add up if you ran multiple instances. If you ran a new Micro EC2 instance that only provides 613MB RAM you're looking at around $21.60 which would save you from the VPS but you've got less RAM which could handle a small static website but if you're using a database that's usually not enough to handle things.

Answer (score 2):

No typically amazon ec2 is more expensive for regular web hosting. Especially when you only need web hosting and wouldn't need shell access (unless you want to do some special stuff on your personal website).

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to rent a "normal" VPS if you are familiar with Linux system administration. A VPS is cheaper and often has useful features, such as a VNC access when the system won't boot up.

Using a cloud instance maybe very interesting, but is maybe the wrong approach here.